# How can I find which calendar's button I clicked?

Tags: java, swing, calendar, jbutton

I was trying to showing Calendar, and if I click the right button I want to make a change to that button's color. Actually I'm going to a pop-up menu, but how do I know which button was clicked first?

```
panel1date.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
for(int i=0; i<btnArr.length;i++){
    btnArr[i] = new Button("");
    btnArr[i].addMouseListener(new MemoHandler());

    panel1date.add(btnArr[i]);
}

btnPrevMon.addActionListener(new BtnEventHandler());
btnNextMon.addActionListener(new BtnEventHandler());


void setDays(Calendar date){
    int year = date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    lblYearMon.setText(year+"year+"+(month+1)+"month");
    Calendar sDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    sDay.set(year, month, 1);
    sDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -sDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)+1);
    for(int i=0; i<btnArr.length; i++, sDay.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)){
        int day = sDay.get(Calendar.DATE);
        btnArr[i].setLabel(day+"");
        if(sDay.get(Calendar.MONTH)!=month) {
            btnArr[i].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        } 
        else {
            btnArr[i].setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    }
}

class BtnEventHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String msg = tf1.getText();
        Button src = (Button)ae.getSource();
        if(src==btnPrevMon) {
            curMon.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        }
        else
            if(src==btnNextMon) {
                curMon.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                setDays(curMon);
                repaint();
            }
    }

    class EventHandler extends FocusAdapter implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String msg = tf1.getText();
            if("".equals(msg))
                return;
            if(dataOut!=null) {
                try {
                    dataOut.writeUTF(nickname+">"+msg);
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                }
            }
            ta1.append("\r\n" + nickname +">"+ msg);
            tf1.setText("");
        }
    }

    class MemoHandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener{

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                diarymemo = new DiaryButtonMemo(Client.server_ip, Client.server_port);
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                btnArr[].setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DiaryClient di = new DiaryClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the button color, use:

```
Color background;
button.setBackground(background);
```

To display a popup menu:

```
public class PopupMenu extends JPanel {
  JPopupMenu popup;

  public PopupMenu() {
    popup = new JPopupMenu();
    JMenuItem item;
    popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Popup"));
    item.addActionListener(new new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // Action performed
        System.out.println("I know which popup menu item ["
          + event.getActionCommand() +
          "] was pressed.");
      });
    });

    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        doPopup(e);
      }

      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        doPopup(e);
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        doPopup(e);
      }

      private void doPopup(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
          popup.show(PopupMenu.this, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```